# how to align \item in enumeration list that has an image so it is symmetrical

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I'd like to add a small tiny image on the same line as an `\item` entry, something like

```
\item \href{index.htm}{some other link} \includegraphics[...]
```

But having hard time getting it to look the way I want it. Here is what I do now

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some other link} 
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\item \href{index.html}{another link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks like when compiled

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I want is like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried using a small table, but that did not help

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \href{index.htm}{some other link}&
      \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
     \end{tabular}
\item \href{index.html}{another link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\end{enumerate}
```

It got a little closer to what I want, but not exactly

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is the correct way to do this in Latex to obtain what I want as shown above?

TL 2018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy with `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some other link}
      \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign= c]{example-image-a}
\item \href{index.html}{another link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also without packages using the TeX primitive `\vcenter` in a new macro for convenience:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\imcenter}[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some other link}
      \imcenter{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\item \href{index.html}{another link}
\item \href{index.htm}{some link}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> [image]