# Using adjustbox in tex4ht does not work. Is this known limitation?

Tags: tex4ht, adjustbox

This MWE, thanks for solution from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463054/how-to-align-item-in-enumeration-list-that-has-an-image-so-it-is-symmetrical)

```
%-----------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign= c]{example-image-a}
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}
\end{document} 
%-----------------------------
```

Produces correct alignment in pdf, but not in HTML after
doing `make4ht foo.tex`

Here is a screen shot of HTML and PDF side by side so you
can see the difference:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a known limitation? Probably a custom CSS configuration
can work around this. But it would be better to avoid this if
possible.

This is TL 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, small piece of CSS can fix that:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Css{li img{vertical-align:middle;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`tex4ht` doesn't try to match visual appearance of the PDF version in HTML, so it is necessary to style it according to your needs sometimes.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: you always supports anything about TeX4ht...much thanks to you...

Comment: Thank you Michal for the help. Your solution works well. But unfortunately it stops working when I added the package  `\usepackage{enumitem}`. I needed `enumitem` to make `\setlist[enumerate]{font=\scriptsize}`. I will try to find another way to make the item list numbers smaller without using `enumitem`. It seems using `enumitem` changed what tex4ht uses for list items so the CSS fix no longer have an effect.

Comment: @Nasser it is just necessary to find what tags are used and use it instead of `<li>`.